# Chapter heading style?

Tags: sectioning, chapters

Hi I ran into a PHD thesis with a beautiful layout. Specially I love its chapter heading [image]

I link also the thesis: http://www.ri.cmu.edu/pub_files/pub4/pantofaru_caroline_2008_1/pantofaru_caroline_2008_1.pdf .
Does anybody known how to obtain this chapter heading?
Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: book, but I can change of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `titlesec`. Here is a sample.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\titlerule[1pt]\vskip12pt\Large\filcenter\MakeUppercase}

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Large\filcenter\MakeUppercase}[{\vskip12pt\titlerule[1pt]}]

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{20pt}{40pt}                    %% adjust  suit
\titlespacing*{name=\chapter,numberless} {0pt}{0pt}{40pt}     %% adjust to suit
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, unfortunately I've found a problem using your solution: the titles like Contents and list of acronyms appear under the underline.... However they should be up their underline for a good look. As the linked thesis... Any ideas?

Comment: @Kevin You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

My apologies, this is a shameless self-promotion by me! This is a simple style I created for my thesis. It's not the style OP wanted, but may be the OP or someone will like this too.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]
{\chapterfont\bfseries\huge}
{\raisedrule[0.175em]{1pt}\Large\filleft\textsc{ \chaptertitlename} \Huge\thechapter}
{2ex}
{\vspace{1ex}%
\filcenter}
[\vspace{1ex}]
```

[image]